# Python - beginner help - How can I append multiple values to a list?

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

I am a beginner to python and am trying to learn beginner concepts such as lists, conditionals and appending. I am trying to make a program which looks at a number, checks if it is even or odd and then appends it to either an even or odd list.

But with this code I can only change the num value each time and it puts 1 value into either list, how can I do this for multiple numbers? Thanks

```
evenList = []
oddList = []

num = 1

if num%2==0:
    evenList.append(num)
else:
    oddList.append(num)

print("even list: " + str(evenList))
print("odd list: " + str(oddList))
```

Comment: You need to use [loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp). In particular, the section titled "The range function" in the link.

Comment: Where are the numbers you need to check coming from?

Comment: If you have numbers stored in another list you can use `list.extend()`

Comment: `new_list = some_list + some_other_list`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of numbers:

```
numbers = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

you can iterate over them:

```
for num in numbers:
```

The colon marks the beginning of a block. This is where to put your code which will use each `num` in the list of `numbers`.

Your code for checking odd/even needs to be indented to be in the block:

```
for num in numbers:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        evenList.append(num)
    else:
        oddList.append(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
num = 1
if num%2==0:
    evenList.append(num)
else:
    oddList.append(num)
```

with something like:

```
for num in range(20):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        evenList.append(num)
    else:
        oddList.append(num)
```

Now you'll have a bunch of different values of `num` to append to your lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the lines separated by a character (, or blank, or newline, eg)
you can do the following:

print (','.join(str(e) for e in evenList))

where the ','  may be replaced with any character you wish, including '\n'  if you want each list item on a separate line

Answer (score 0):

Making your program a little dynamic will do some tricks

```
#how many numbers do you want to check?

input1 = int(input("input your desired length of numbers you want to check"))
evenList = []
oddList = []
for i in range(input1):
    #Enter the number you wish to check
    num = int(input("input an integer "))
    if num % 2 == 0:
        evenList.append(num)
    else:
        oddList.append(num)

print("even list: " + str(evenList))
print("odd list: " + str(oddList))
#you can use this print alternatively
#print(f"even list: {evenList}")
#print(f"odd list: {oddList}")
```